stateFlow value changes, but subscribers are not notified
I use koin and jetpack compose. and when I update the stateFlow value, subscribers are not informed and there is no recomposition in the composable functions.
part of code in view model:
private val _audio = MutableStateFlow(Audio())
val audio: StateFlow<Audio> get() = _audio

fun updateAudio(newAudio: Audio) {
    Log.i(TAG, "updateAudio: ${audio.value}")
    _audio.value = newAudio
    Log.i(TAG, "updateAudio: ${audio.value}")
}
...

value of _audio.value changes, but subscribers are not notified
log:
updateAudio: Audio(id=-1, title=Dj Ess - Change My Wayz Mixxx, artist=<unknown>, ...)
updateAudio: Audio(id=-1, title=lungskull - magic, artist=<unknown>, ...)


part of the composable func:
@Composable
fun PlayingTrackBottomBar(
    onClick: (Audio) -> Unit = {},
    playerServiceViewModel: PlayerServiceViewModel = koinViewModel()
) {
    val audio by playerServiceViewModel.audio.collectAsState()
    ...
}

also subscribed to change the value in the view model itself
viewModelScope.launch {
   audio.collect {
       Log.i(TAG, "init: $it")
   }
}

I've tried different options (live data, state flow, state) but nothing helped
looking at the logs, I found that the stateFlow value is changing, but none of the subscribers are notified

How do you call the updateAudio? Do you maybe modify the existing Audio object? What's the implementation of Audio?

Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] that we can execute to reproduce the problem.

when I called koinViewModel(), different instances of this view model were created in different composable functions.
i created my modelViewStoreOwner and specified it in the parameters of the koinViewModel owner
object GlobalViewModelStoreOwner : ViewModelStoreOwner {
private val _viewModelStore = ViewModelStore()

override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore
    get() = _viewModelStore

created func returned viewModel
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getGlobalViewModel(viewModelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return koinViewModel(viewModelStoreOwner = GlobalViewModelStoreOwner, key = "singleton")
}

and called:
playerServiceViewModel = getGlobalViewModel(viewModelClass = PlayerServiceViewModel::class.java)

